# Date formatter from RSS feed to "time.ago"

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

Im trying to create RSS feed webpage and RSS answer with date formatted this `"Thu, 15 Aug 2013 12:42:05 -0700"` wat and I want to change it intom for example `"12 minutes ago"`. I tried http://timeago.yarp.com/ but it doesn't really work with this format. I want to achieve this in javascript. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), usage:

```
moment("Thu, 15 Aug 2013 12:42:05 -0700").fromNow() // 8 hours ago
```